# A Replacement for "Free tour guide"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

In France, there are people who welcome tourists into cities in a *free* manner, where said tourists do not need to pay for a guided visit around town, who are introduced to the local scene without needing to pay and without any restrictions nor commitments.

The closest English equivalent I could come up with was "greeter". But "greeter" for me has a more 'temporary' sense, that is to say that (normally) one doesn't 'greet' a person for several hours with a visit around town. "Volunteer tour guide" also comes to mind, but it just doesn't seem right...

Is there a good term to describe this kind of person?

Comment: "Welcome party"  , "Reception Committee"

Comment: Could either of those two phrases represent a *single person* though? The words "party" and "committee" both give me the idea of multiple persons.

Comment: They may initially give you the idea of multiple persons but both words are acceptable/legitimate when applied to 1-person teams.

Comment: I think you've already nailed it with "volunteer tour guide". Prefixing volunteer to some role usually implies the person is not being paid (although it doesn't preclude them from receiving expenses etc).

Comment: Why not *welcome guide*?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Why does saying "volunteer guide" for "guide bénévole" sound wrong to you? http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/bénévole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In France, we call volunteer tour guides "guides bénévoles" i.e. "*benevolent* tour guides."

Consider "[nonprofit tour guides](https://www.energizeinc.com/news/2010-jul-dec.html)" and "not-for-profit tour guides" as possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say that a "Complimentary Guided Tour" is available

Comment: "Complimentary tour" emphasizes that the tourist doesn't pay, not that the guide is unpaid.

Comment: Is the guide unpaid?

Comment: Yes, "volunteer" in the OP implies that the guide is not someone who is paid/employed to do that. And the question is the OP was trying to name the type of guide, not the type of tour.

Comment: I like this one but would change the word arrangement to Complimentary Tour Guide.  The phrase tour guide doesn't infer payment, it is just something that someone does.

Answer (score 0):

There's [docent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_docent) but that's more usually used for museums than towns.

I suggest "host".